# Как получить реальные координаты(X,Y) Bitmap'a из imageView Android

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, координаты

Моя проблема заключается в следующем :
я получаю изображение(не важно каким образом), затем конвертирую Bitmap и устанавливаю его в контрол ImageView.

Для лучшей наглядности, я добавил фото
[image: What i have]
Как показано на рисунке у изображения разрешение отличается достаточно большое разрешение. Суть заключается в том, что пользователь сможет делать перспективу(посредством кружков желтых,которые представляют собой координаты).

Другими словами,мне нужно получить реальные координаты(пиксели) Bitmapa,через ImageView(который имеет совсем другое разрешение **Width**/**Height**).
Через реализацию TouchListener'a , я получаю координаты с ImageView(те самые, желтые точки).

На текущий момент пробовал следующее(но это не правильный подход,да и не правильный результат):

```
   Bitmap bt = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Activity.Resources, Resource.Drawable.test),800,1420,false); //800 width 1420 height
                    imgView.SetImageBitmap(bt);
```

Результат отрицательный.
Затем делал следующее :

```
Drawable GetDrawable = imgView.Drawable;
                    Android.Graphics.Rect ImageBounds = GetDrawable.Bounds;
  //оригинальные размеры изображения,которое загружено в ImageView
 int OriginalHeight = GetDrawable.IntrinsicHeight;
                    int OriginalWidth = GetDrawable.IntrinsicWidth;
                //измененые,после того как пихнули в ImageView
                int ScaledHeight = ImageBounds.Height();
                int ScaledWidth = ImageBounds.Width();
                 //считаем соотношение
                float HeighRatio = OriginalHeight/ScaledHeight;
                float WidthRatio = OriginalWidth/ScaledWidth;
                //point словарь с координатами Х,У
                float ScaledImageOffsetX = points[0].X - (float)ImageBounds.Left;
                float ScaledImageOffsetY = points[0].Y - (float)ImageBounds.Top;

                float OriginalImageOffsetX = ScaledImageOffsetX * WidthRatio;
                float OriginalImageOffsetY = ScaledImageOffsetY * HeighRatio;
```

А после пробовал по формуле :

```
ТочкаХ = ПолученнаяКординатаЧерезМетодGetX() /ImageView.Width;
ТочкаУ =  ПолученнаяКординатаЧерезМетодGetY() /ImageView.Height;
```

К сожалению тоже безуспешно.
Как можно заполучить эти "реальные" координаты?

Comment: "К сожалению тоже безуспешно." как понять безуспешно ? Приложение вылетает с ошибкой или координаты не корректные получаете?

Comment: Реальные, а не приблизительные координаты вы сможете получить только в том случае, когда 1 пиксель на битмепе равен 1 пикселю в `ImageView`. Во всех остальных случаях вам придется примерно рассчитывать координаты одним из способов ,которые вы привели.

Comment: @Andrew да,координаты не те.

Comment: @metalurgus да,тоже так думал.НО в идеале такого не получить(ибо качество изображения будет страдать).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем решение проблемы оказалось в следующем:
Необходимо получить инвертированную матрицу из ImageView и затем,при помощи метода **mapPoints** получать реальные координаты.

```
 final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(iv);
        // setup your image here by 
        // calling for example iv.setImageBitmap()
        // or iv.setImageDrawable()
        // or iv.setImageResource()
        View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                iv.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
                float[] pts = {
                        event.getX(), event.getY()
                };
                inverse.mapPoints(pts);
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch x: " + Math.floor(pts[0]) + ", y: " + Math.floor(pts[1]));
                return false;
            }
        };
        iv.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```